# Delete Selected Text in a Text Box

Tags: vba, textbox

Hey fellow Stackoverflow users,

i'm trying to create a text editor with HTML tag functions (for export) and can't get a solution working. Therefor i created a textbox where the user should be able to insert the text. For this insert function i need the in the title described function to delete the selected text (only the selected text, the text around it stays) inside the textbox. Even SendKeys won't function right.

Please let me know if anyone got an idea, thanks upfront!

EDIT: Here's the corrected code for the bold button with maintextbox as textbox for the user's text:

```
Private Sub BoldButton_Click()
If maintextbox.SelLength = 0 Then
MsgBox ("Please highlight the text you want to edit!")
Else
SelectionText = maintextbox.SelText MsgBox ("SelText: " & SelectionText)
maintextbox.SelText = "<b>" & _
SelectionText & _
"</b>"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Comment: The corrected code for the bold button with maintextbox as textbox for the user's text:

`Private Sub BoldButton_Click()

If maintextbox.SelLength = 0 Then
MsgBox ("Please highlight the text you want to edit!")
Else
SelectionText = maintextbox.SelText
MsgBox ("SelText: " & SelectionText)
maintextbox.SelText = "<b>" & _
SelectionText & _
"</b>"
End If

End Sub`

Comment: Jan, please copy the code into your question.  It'll be much easier to read and more people, looking for this answer, will see it as well.

Comment: Just inserted the code, thanks for the idea Jimmy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
TextBox.SelText = ""
```

The `.Sel*` methods all relate to the text currently selected within the control. `SelText = ""` replaces the current selection with nothing, thereby deleting it whilst preserving the surrounding unselected text.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so simple. Thanks for the help Alex!